# Apply function to some elements of list

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of complex objects i.e.

```
class MyObject 
{
    public bool selected;
    public int id;
    public string name;
}

List<MyObject> theObjects = functionThatSelectsObjectsFromContainer();
```

And I have a list from another source that just give me int ids that are in the list of objects

```
List<int> idList = functionThatReturnsListOfIds();
```

Now for each of the items in the idList I want to set the `selected` property true. I know I can set up a foreach of one list and then search for the matching items in the other list and set it that way, but I was wondering if there's a different way that might be quicker.

Comment: Consider using LINQ Join function. Try theObjects.Join(idList, o => o.id, id => id, (o, id) => o).

Comment: Thanks @KrzysztofUkl. Your answer appears to be the right solution as demonstrated by the test trials bassie put together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Conclusion

I did some testing on all my methods below, as well as **un-lucky**'s answer, and the fastest of them all was option **2** below, ie

```
var results = theObjects.Join(idList, o => o.id, id => id, (o, id) => o).ToList();
results.ForEach(o => o.selected = true);
```

---

Another way of doing it with Linq, where we iterate around `theObjects` and check each one to see if its' id exists in `idList`:

**1**

```
var result = theObjects.ForEach(o => o.selected = idList.Contains(o.id) ? true : false);
```

or using `Join` and `ForEach`, where we first extract the matching items using `Join` and then iterate around those items:

**2**

```
var results = theObjects.Join(idList, o => o.id, id => id, (o, id) => o).ToList();
results.ForEach(o => o.selected = true);
```

or, you can use `Select` with `ForEach` and `FirstOrDefault`. This is probably going to be slower than the other 2:

**3**

```
theObjects
    .Select(o => o.id)
    .Where(i => idList.Contains(i)).ToList()
    .ForEach(i => 
        theObjects.FirstOrDefault(o => o.id == i).selected = true);
```

---

I did some testing on the 3 methods I posted, where we have 10000 `MyObject`s and 1000 unique ids. I ran each method 1000 times, and then got the mean `ElapsedMillliseconds` for each.

The results were

### 1

8.288 ms

### 2

0.19 ms

### 3

57.342 ms

```
one = 0;
two = 0;
three = 0;

for (var i = 0; i <1000; i++) {
    RunTest();
}

oneMean = one / 1000;
twoMean = two / 1000;
threeMean = three / 1000;
```

where

```
private void RunTest()
{
    ResetData();
    var stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    theObjects.ForEach(o => o.selected = idList.Contains(o.id) ? true : false);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    one += stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    ResetData();
    stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    var results = theObjects.Join(idList, o => o.id, id => id, (o, id) => o).ToList();
    results.ForEach(o => o.selected = true);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    two += stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;

    ResetData();
    stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    theObjects
        .Select(o => o.id)
        .Where(i => idList.Contains(i)).ToList()
        .ForEach(i => 
            theObjects.FirstOrDefault(o => o.id == i).selected = true);
    stopwatch.Stop();
    three += stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
}

private void ResetData()
{
    theObjects = new List<MyObject>();
    idList = new List<int>();
    var rnd = new Random();

    for (var i=0; i<10000; i++) {
        theObjects.Add(new MyObject(){id = i});
    }
    for (var i=0; i<=1000; i++) {

        var r = rnd.Next(0, 1000);
        while (idList.Contains(r)) {
            r = rnd.Next(0, 10000);
        }
        idList.Add(r);
    }
}
```

I tested **un-lucky**'s answer (most upvotes right now) and it got a mean score of 147.676

```
foreach(var obj in theObjects.Where(o => idList.Any(i=> i == o.id)))
{
    obj.selected = true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the suggestions and thanks @bassie for the work on testing. Option 2 is the clear winner for speed even though there's a join & a foreach.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do something like this, to make that working

```
foreach(var obj in theObjects.Where(o => idList.Any(i=> i == o.id)))
{
    obj.selected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With the help of **Linq**, you can use *Where*, *ToList* and *ForEach* to achieve your required behaviour -

```
theObjects.Where(x => idList.Contains(x.id)).ToList().ForEach(y => y.selected = true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using linq you can do like so

```
theObjects.Where(g => idList.Contains(g.id)).ForEach(g => g.selected = true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below solution where you don't need to use `Where` and `Contains`:

```
theObjects.ForEach(a => a.selected = idList.Exists(b => a.id == b));
```